# Automatically generating PDF's in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf

I'm currently working on a ruby on rails project. I need the system to automatically generate a PDF every 12 hours based off information from a data base.

Currently I'm looking at the prawn gem to generate the PDF's but I was wondering if there was a way to make this gem (or any other) produce the PDF every so many hours.

Comment: Take a look at this gem https://github.com/javan/whenever to use cron jobs to produce the PDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how to generate PDFs via Ruby (using `prawn` or `wicked_pdf`), there are only 2 steps left to take:

1. Create a rake task, call it, like this:

   ```
   # lib/tasks/my_pdf_task.rake

   desc "Generate pdf"
   task :generate_pdf => :environment do
     MyPdfGenerator.new.generate
   end
   ```
2. Run it via cron, using [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem. After installing & initializing the gem, edit the `config/schedule.rb`:

   ```
   # config/schedule.rb

   every 3.hours do
     rake "generate_pdf"
   end
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can be achieved by using [Wicked PDF](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf). From my past understanding and your question it seems that you want to generate some sort of email that contains the attachment pdf. If I stand correctly you would have something like this in your mailer.

```
 def overtime_pdf(user, booking)
    @bookings = booking
    @user = user
    mail(:subject => 'Overtime', :to => user.email) do |format|
      format.text # renders overtime_pdf.text.erb for body of email
      format.pdf do
        attachments['bookings.pdf'] = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
            render_to_string(:pdf => 'overtime', :template =>
                'bookings/index.pdf.erb', :layouts => 'pdf.html')
        )
      end
    end
  end
```

Upon doing this if you are using heroku you can use `heroku-scheduler`. What you want to do is create a class method that take a user argument, then you can pass the user in the controller action and use this in the rake task. So you could have something like this.

**Class**

```
 def self.send_overtime_mail(user, bookings)
    BookingMailer.booking_pdf(user, bookings).deliver
  end
```

**Rake task**

```
task :overtime_report => :environment do
  every 3.hours do
    user = User.where(:role => :administrator).first
    bookings = Bookings.where(:day => Date.today.beginning_of_month..Date.today.end_of_month)
    Booking.send_overtime_mail(user, bookings)
  end
end
```